# TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have created a get_config function in order to pass two parameters to my main function. I seem to be getting the following error when running my script :

```
File "querysearch.py", line 14, in main
    search_type = get_config[0]
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Am i passing the args the wrong way ? My script is as follows :

```
import argparse

def get_config():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search your keyword ex: querycheck.py andsearch general,population,Alzheimer')
    parser.add_argument('searchtype', type=str, help='Search type orsearch and andsearch only ')
    parser.add_argument('Value', type=str, help='Parameter to search')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return [args.searchtype , args.Value]


def main(get_config):
    finallist = []
    counter = 0
    search_type = get_config[0]
    value = get_config[1]


    if search_type == "orsearch":
        _prasplit = value.split(",")
        with open("hscic-news", "r") as newsfile:
            ncontent = newsfile.readlines()
            for x in range(len(ncontent)):
                for y in _prasplit:
                    if y in ncontent[x]:
                        finallist.append(x)


    #   print (list(set(finallist)))
        list_with_duplicates = list(set(finallist))
        final_list = list(set(finallist))
        result = final_list
        print(result)
```

Comment: `get_config` is a *function*, and you're not actually *calling* it. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: @jonrsharpe

I am calling it if you look at my variables search_type and value ?

Comment: No, you aren't. That's also what the error message is telling you; you're trying to index into it, which doesn't make sense because it's a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually calling the get_config function.

Change the last line of your get_config function to `return args.searchtype, args.Value`.

Then, change the lines in your main function to `search_type, value = get_config()`.